# Cross database query between Google SQL instances (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

Since DBlink is not available in Google SQL, I was wondering if it is possible to query a different SQL instance in the same GCP project.
I've put in place a separate process inside the console to query both databases from there but I was wondering if there is something more straightforward that can allow me to query one database from the other (like dblink in a normal PostgreSQL install).

Comment: There are some other users with the same issue. I have found this [Feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62117904), where you can follow the process from the team in charge.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, in order to create dblink with PostgreSQL,  you need to install "dblink" extension.

Unfortunately this extension is not supported in GCP Cloud SQL at the moment as you can see here :
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/extensions

I wish there is some kind of workaround for this problem but I am not aware of any.

Comment: Kindly consider editing this post to reflect that GCP Cloud SQL now supports this and has a postgres_fdw instead of posting a new Answer.

Answer (score 0):

FDW extension is something that allows call to different DB. Everything is in their docs. [Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/postgres-fdw.html) is direct link to PG docs, with simple example. Besides that - there is PL/Proxy. That is a bit something else, but remote calls are also possible - [here](https://github.com/plproxy/plproxy/blob/master/doc/tutorial.md) is their tutorial.